# Перемещение данных из одной таблицы в другую с разной структурой

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно перенести данные из одной таблицы в другую по соответствующему id. Проблема в том, что у таблиц структура разная.
Структура следующая у первой таблицы: table1.id1, table1.pole1, **table1.pole2**.
Bторая таблица: table2.id2, table2.pole3, table2.pole4, **table2.pole2.**
Совпадают только выделенные поля.

Comment: а остальные чем заполнять? у них установлены значения по умолчанию?

Comment: id во второй таблице автоинкремент, еще два поля будут статичными, т.е будут задаваться значения через код.

Comment: Вы просто всю таблицу перенести хотите или только строки по соответствию id1 = id2 ?

Comment: `INSERT INTO table2 (table2.id2, table2.pole3, table2.pole4, table2.pole2) SELECT id1, pole3value, pole2value, table1.pole2  FROM   table1`